# EXTJS: scrolling issue

Tags: extjs

When Data loads in grid and scrolling appears, I can navigate it through up/down arror key. But when the pointer goes down not able to see the content in grid, i mean the grid does not shift upword automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your grid is not rendered properly. Judging by your description your grid is bigger then the panel it belongs to. Please post some code and screenshots.